# Exception while mapping generic property in Hibernate entity

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

We are migrating from hibernate XML to annotation and we got this exception while starting EAR after mapping generic property.

```
Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.hibernate.AnnotationException: Use of @OneToMany or @ManyToMany targeting an unmapped class: com.AppTerminalTypeCriteria.devicePropertiesCriteria
```

This is the code related to this exception.

The mapped property In AppTerminalTypeCriteria class

```
@javax.persistence.Entity
@Table(name = "TYPE_CRITERIA")
public class AppTerminalTypeCriteria {
//Some fields
    @OneToMany(orphanRemoval = true)
    @JoinTable(inverseJoinColumns=@JoinColumn(name="APP_CRITERIA_PROPERTY_ID"))
    @org.hibernate.annotations.Cache(usage = CacheConcurrencyStrategy.TRANSACTIONAL)
    private Set<PropertyCriteria<?>> devicePropertiesCriteria = new HashSet<PropertyCriteria<?>>();

}
```

PropertyCriteria entity

```
@Entity(name="PropertyCriteria")
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.SINGLE_TABLE)
@Table(name = "PROPERTY_CRITERIA")
@DiscriminatorColumn(name = "PROPERTY_CRITERIA_TYPE", discriminatorType = DiscriminatorType.STRING)
public abstract class PropertyCriteria<T extends Comparable<T>> implements Serializable {
// the rest of the class 
}
```

And one of the sub-classes of PropertyCriteria

```
@Entity
@DiscriminatorValue("5")
public class BooleanPropertyCriteria extends PropertyCriteria<Boolean> {

}
```

And this is the XML mapping that we try to get rid of

In AppTerminalTypeCriteria.hbm.xml

```
<set name="devicePropertiesCriteria" inverse="false" cascade="all-delete-orphan">
            <cache usage="transactional" />
            <key column="APP_CRITERIA_PROPERTY_ID" />
            <one-to-many
                class="PropertyCriteria"
                entity-name="PropertyCriteria" />
</set>
```

And in PropertyCriteria.hbm.xml

```
<class name="PropertyCriteria" table="PROPERTY_CRITERIA" entity-name="PropertyCriteria">
<discriminator type="string" column="PROPERTY_CRITERIA_TYPE" />
<subclass name="com.emeint.server.core.propertycriteria.BooleanPropertyCriteria" discriminator-value="5" />
```

How to fix this exception?

Comment: So, your XML mapping knows nothing of Generics?

Comment: @Smutje yes it seems so

Comment: Hibernate seems to have its problems with Generics and as Generics are also not a database concept I suggest to keep them out of your entities - and if you want to use them anyway rather have a second layer of domain objects on top of your entities that represent the domain model using normal Java mechanisms (like Generics). Mixing responsibilities is seldom a good idea and at least I try to keep entities as close to the database structure as possible.

Comment: Please show annotations on `AppTerminalTypeCriteria` class

Comment: @NikolaiShevchenko I added the annotations on this class, is this what you mean?

Answer (score 0):

The error message clearly says that the entity is not registered in the persistence unit. Maybe you didn't list this PropertyCriteria.hbm.xml in the persistence.xml as `mapping-file`?

Comment: We are migrating from XML to annotations, so we removed mapping PropertyCriteria.hbm.xml

Comment: Have you listed that class in the persistence.xml as `<class>`?

Comment: We don't have to. Other entities are working just fine without defining them in some place.

Comment: I don't know how your application is structured, maybe the class isn't part of your deployment or one of the packages that are scanned? Try to debug to the point where the exception occurs and find out for sure if the entity is recognized by Hibernate. If not, you will have to find out why it's not picked up.